# jQuery .hasClass() vs .is()

Tags: jquery

is there a preferred method of determining whether an element is assigned a class, from a performance standpoint?

```
$('#foo').hasClass('bar');
```

or

```
$('#foo').is('.bar');
```

Comment: You can always validate performance on this site as well over multiple browsers:  http://jsperf.com ...These are some test cases to browse: http://jsperf.com/browse

Answer (score 166, accepted):

### Update:

I committed a test following a comment and four upvotes to very comment. It turns out that what I had said is the correct answer. Here is the result:

[image]

http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-so

---

The [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is multi-purpose, you can for example do `is('.class')`, `is(':checked')`, etc which means `is` has *more to do* where is [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) is limited which only checks for a class being set or not.

Hence, `hasClass` should be faster if performance at any level is your priority.

Comment: Do you have proof that it is faster? Just because a function has less funtionality does NOT mean it's automatically faster.

Comment: @Kris: Yes I do: http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-so. As I said, `hasClass` ***is*** a lot more faster.

Comment: 'a lot more faster' => 'much faster'

Comment: @SgtPooki, I was simply asking for proof; if it was true I wanted to know why. I am inquisitive like that :). You can easily have more functionality and have it be faster; it always depends on implementation. Your 99% is a sweeping generalization and not necessarily the true state of software development. Your question of "Will jQuery ever be as fast as straight JavaScript? An answer other than no is wrong." is not a good question; jQuery actually has many optimizations in which will provide faster access to DOM elements once data is cached; it really depends on your specific usage.

Comment: @SgtPooki "Additional CPU cycles" would mean slower every time I agree but I'm not sure why we're talking about your interpretation. I asked for an explanation because, as I already mentioned, less functionality does not mean faster. I am not sure of your intent to state "Software developers seem to be forgetting all about CPU cycles"; it appears you are stating, indirectly, that I am forgetting about CPU cycles but I am purporting the opposite; additional functionality may not mean additional CPU cycles as it depends on implementation. It always depends on implementation.

Comment: @SgtPooki as far as faster take a look at the sizzle selector engine; as I continue to mention it depends on implementation and in older browsers that do not natively support queries it will most likely be faster through jQuery's implementation as there is no native version (win by default). Also if you're continuing to recall the same DOM elements, depending on browser and version, it may take additional time where as jQuery can cache this element for faster retrieval. Typically native JavaScript functions will be faster; but it depends on browser support and implementation.

Answer (score 14):

Since `is` is more generic than `hasClass` and uses `filter` to process the provided expression, it seems likely that `hasClass` is faster.

I ran the following code from the Firebug console:

```
function usingIs() {
for (var i=0; i<10000;i++) {
 $('div#example-0').is('.test');
}
}

function usingHas(){
for (var i=0; i<10000;i++) {
 $('div#example-0').hasClass('test');
}
}

usingIs();
usingHas();
```

I got:

- usingIs:  3191.663ms
- usingHas: 2362.523ms

Not a huge difference, but may be relevant if you're doing *lots* of testing.

**EDIT** when I say 'not a huge difference, my point is that you need to do 10000 cycles in order to see 0.8s of a difference. I'd be surprised to see a web application such that switching from `is` to `hasClass` would see a significant improvement in over all performance. However, I grant that this is a 35% improvement in speed.

Answer (score 9):

Both should be pretty close in terms of performance but `$('#foo').hasClass('bar');` seems more readable and semantically correct to me.

Answer (score 7):

`.hasClass` is much faster than `.is`
You can test it from [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-hasclass/2). Change the test case according to you.