# jQuery - How to check if element has any of these classes

Tags: jquery, html

Example:

How do I check if div #test has any of `.a1` `.a2` `.a3` `.a4` `.a5` classes? With only one if-statment...

```
<div id="test" class="a1 a2 a5"></div>
```

Comment: Are there only 5 classes to be matched, or do you want to match any class in the form `aN` or `aNN` etc.?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery `is` function](http://api.jquery.com/is/), checking all the classes that you want match.

```
$("#test").is(".a1,.a2,.a3,.a4,.a5")
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thnx :)

Comment: please note that .is() is very slower than .hasClass() , i have added a reply to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hasClass function.

```
var test = $('#test');
if(test.hasClass('a1') || test.hasClass('a2') || test.hasClass('a3') ...) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i just found this thread, and i wanted to clarify that `.is()` is very slower than `hasClass()`

and i found other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901593/2918720) which discusses that.

So, if you care for performance or if you check for large number of elements it is preferred to use `hasClass()`

also you can check jsperf [here](https://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-hasclass/2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#test").hasClass("a1") || $("#test").hasClass("a2") || $("#test").hasClass("a3") || $("#test").hasClass("a4") || $("#test").hasClass("a5")) {

   // Do something

}
```