# Function to check if element has any of these classes with native JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div id="test" class="a1 a2 a5"></div>

var element = document.getElementById("test") 
if (hasAnyOfTheseClasses(element, ["a1", "a6"])) { 
   //...
}
```

Looking for a simple, lightweight function to check if a function has any of the listed classes without jQuery or another library.

Such function would be easy to implement, but there should be a canonical, fastest and simplest answer people can just copy-paste.

**This seems vampire-ish,** but I'm asking this so googlers won't have to write it themselves.

Not a duplicate - the linked question checks for *one* class, this question asks for checking *any* of the classes.

[A jQuery version exists here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049385/jquery-how-to-check-if-element-has-any-of-these-classes)

Comment: Who doesn't want this to be able to copy-paste this sort of code?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard for someone with basic skills. Tried anything yourself?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yes. It works. I'm looking for a canonical answer so googlers won't have to go through that process again. (my impl probably isn't good for performance or elegant)

Comment: If you're looking to post a canonical question, post your solution as an answer. Don't hide behind it as an excuse to get people to write code for you.

Comment: @4castle Okay. Doing it now.

Comment: Not sure if adding a loop needs its own Q&A. Basically a duplicate of  [Test if an element contains a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5898656/218196). The short version would be `['foo', 'bar'].some(cls => element.classList.contains(cls))`

Comment: There's no such thing as `selectElementById`. It's `getElementById`.

Comment: @Barmar keep making that mistake >_<

Comment: This has already been answered, possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5898748/4812515

Comment: @alphapilgrim that is one class, this is multiple classes

Comment: @alphapilgrim Dude, did you read the question before VTC? C'mon, just because -3 doesn't mean dupe.

Comment: *"the linked question checks for one class, this question asks for checking any of the classes."* Can we assume that developers know how to repeat something multiple times?

Comment: @noɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Your answer looks alot like the answer from that question. Just with a for loop. Just saying.

Comment: @FelixKling Different canonical answers though. `.classList.contains()` is much better than the tricky method described there. Also google hits.

Comment: @alphapilgrim Somebody requested I post my bad code. I did.

Comment: *"`.classList.contains()` is much better than the tricky method described there."* The answer says *"Alternatively, if you work with a browser which supports `element.classList`, you can use its `.contains` method: ..."* Also if you look at the end of the answer, you can see that it actually applies the test in a loop ;) Just saying :)

Comment: @FelixKling Hard to find by google. Overlapping answer ≠ no need for new question.

Comment: *"Hard to find by google."* That's what duplicate questions are for. The dupes are sign posts to the canonical Q&A.

Comment: @FelixKling ...and how many people will see that tiny note?

Comment: Tiny? It's 25% of the answer! But whatever, I don't care. Just make sure to link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class/5898748 in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional implementation using [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Element.classList.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
function hasAnyClass(element, classes) {
  return classes.some(function(c) {
    return element.classList.contains(c);
  });
}

var div = document.getElementById("test");
console.log(hasAnyClass(div, ["hi", "xyz"]));
console.log(hasAnyClass(div, ["xyz", "there"]));
console.log(hasAnyClass(div, ["xyz", "xyz"]));
```

```html
<div id="test" class="hi there"></div>
```

Note that these functions are not supported on older versions of IE, and will require a shim/polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
function hasAnyOfTheseClasses(element, classes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if ((' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + classes[i] + ' ') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's not elegant or fast. Works though. Feel free to edit to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex, not sure that it's purely better but at least more flexible since your current test relies too much on spaces being entered correctly.

```
function hasAnyOfTheseClasses(element, classes) {
    var className = element.className;
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        var exp = new RegExp('\b'+classes[i] + '\b');
      if(exp.test(className)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *"relies too much on spaces being entered correctly"* I don't think so. How could that be an issue? That's also the implementation that jQuery uses btw.

Answer (score 0):

just create a loop that check if each value in your array is a class in your passed element

```
function hasAnyOfTheseClasses(elem, tofind) {
    classes = elem.className.split(' ');
    for(var x in tofind) {
        var className = tofind[x];
        if (classes.indexOf(className) == -1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: misusage of `for (... in ...)`

Comment: mine does too. And this one has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property to get the list of classes of an element. Then you can use the `.contains()` method to test each of the classes.

```
function hasAnyOfTheseClass(element, classes) {
    var classList = element.classList;
    return classes.some(function(class) {
        return classList.contains(class);
    });
}
```

Comment: Duped by Felix's answer.

Comment: Oh dear, this answer is popular 3 times over

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
function hasAnyClass(el, classes) {
  var elClasses = el.className.split(' ');
  return classes.some(c => elClasses.indexOf(c) >= 0)
}
```