# Difference between 'hasClass' and 'is'? Also, alternative to return Jquery element instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .hasClass() vs .is()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901553/jquery-hasclass-vs-is)

HTML code:

```
<div class="results">
    <div class="table">
        <form class="tr" action="#" method="post">
            <div class="td">
                <input class="datepicker" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                <input class="datepicker" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$('.results').find('input:text').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var b = element.hasClass('.datepicker');
    var c = element.is('.datepicker');
}
```

My question:

'is' and 'hasClass' is supposed to both return true when it finds an  element containing the class "datepicker", correct?

Somehow, it's not.  'hasClass' returns false, and 'is' returns true.

Also, I've been digging for a solution to do some chaining jquery calls.  But both 'hasClass' and 'is' returns a boolean only.  Is there a JQuery function that returns a $(Jquery) element so I can do something like this?  I already tried "filter" function, but seems to not work.

```
element.SomeFunctionToDigUpAnElementWithClass('datepicker').DoSomeCoolStuff();
```

================================================================

Comment: Use of `.hasClass` is much appropriate than using `.is` for this specific case.

Comment: `filter` does do what I believe you are describing.  I would guess you are somehow using it incorrectly.

Comment: What happend to reading the documentation? It contains examples as well! http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/, http://api.jquery.com/is/.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: That's about performance differences, not what the functions are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer guys.  Actually, I was more of looking for a solution to return a JQuery element instead of returning boolean.  Are there alternative functions that do this?

Comment: hasClass should return true if you do `.hasClass('datepicker');` without the `.`

Comment: `it finds an element containing the class "datepicker", correct?` WRONG. It returns true if the first element in the result set has the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hasClass()` is more specific and a faster operation. is() allows you to select a wider range, for example you can do `is(':checked')`

http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-so

Answer (score 8):

`hasClass` without the dot, of course, because it's a class name. `is` on the other hand any selector.

```
element.hasClass('datepicker');
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep chaining you need to modify your selector:

```
$('.results').find('input:text.datepicker').doSomething();
```

or with `each` if you need to pass specific parameters to the next function for each input element:

```
$('.results').find('input:text.datepicker').each(function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

If you need to do something for the inputs without datepicker class set use `:not` selector:

```
$('.results').find('input:text:not(.datepicker)').doSomething();
```

Or even without `find`:

```
$('.results input:text.datepicker').doSomething();
```

Comment: Best answer so far, with no up votes... Sad.