# Get the next div and check that div for a class exists in it's childs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How do I determinate if one of the buttons have the class "selected"?

```
<a id="foo">Foo</a>
<div id="div">
    <input type="button" />
    <input type="button" class="selected" />
    <input type="button" />
</div>
```

I wrap foo into a jQuery object. Call next() to get to the div. How do I do the rest?

```
function fooClickHandler(foo) {
    var $self = $(foo);
    var selectedExists = $self.next().children('input .selected');
};
```

Comment: you can use `find` instead of `children` to use any selector you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is looking for a descendant of a `input` element with class `selected` which is not possible as input element cann't have children.

If you want to have a boolean value, you can use

```
var selectedExists = $self.next().children('input').hasClass('selected'); //or .is('.selected');
//here `selectedExists` will be a boolean value
```

If you want to have reference to the `input` element then

```
var selectedExists = $self.next().children('input.selected');
//here `selectedExists` will refer to the `input` element with class `selected` if there is one, else it will be empty jQuery object.
```

Comment: I can see in the doc. the is returns true/false. I have to check in javascript after on the value.
Do you prefer next() or find() as robert commented on my question?

Comment: I will use "hasClass" and not "is". But thanks for showing an alternative so I know about both.
hasClass() vs is() benchmark:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901553/jquery-hasclass-vs-is

Answer (score 1):

use below code to check input have class 'selected'

```
var selectedExists = $self.next().children('input').hasClass('selected');
```

hasClass() return true if class assign to element