# JQuery check a specific class name is available in an element even there is multiple class names

Tags: jquery

```
var cName = $(".cm_lhs").children("div").first().attr('class');
if (cName == "tile_nav") {
alert(cName);
}
```

How to check element class name contains at least the class name "tile_nav" if there is multiple class names?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .hasClass() vs .is()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901553/jquery-hasclass-vs-is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if ($(".cm_lhs").children("div").first().hasClass("tile_nav")) {
     alert("Yes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
var firstC = $(".cm_lhs").children("div").first();
if (firstC.is(".tile_nav")) {
    alert("Present");
}
```

**or** [**hasClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
var firstC = $(".cm_lhs").children("div").first();
 if (firstC.hasClass("tile_nav")) {
        alert("Present");
 }
```

**or** do it manually

```
var cName = $(".cm_lhs").children("div").first().attr('class');
if (cName.split(' ').indexOf('tile_nav') > -1) {
    alert("Present");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass` method as follow:

```
if ($(".cm_lhs").children("div").first().hasClass("tile_nav")) {
    alert("Class present");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can use `hasClass()`

```
 if($(".cm_lhs").children("div").first().hasClass('tile_nav')){
    alert(cName);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `hasClass()` of jquery

For e.g.

```
if ($(".cm_lhs").children("div").first().hasClass("tile_nav")) {
alert(cName);
}
```

This works

Comment: this was already answered 4 times and cname is no longer available to alert