# How to skip element with specific class in jQuery for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements:

```
<ul id="wpsl-stores">
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li class="skipthis">list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li class="skipthis">list</li>
    <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looping through the elements and appending the number of that element:

```
var locCount = $('#wpsl-stores li').length;


for (i = 1; i < locCount+1; i++) {

    $('#wpsl-stores ul li:nth-child('+i+') strong:before').hide();

    $('body').append('<style>#wpsl-stores ul li:nth-child('+i+') strong:before {content:"'+i+'";}</style>');    

}
```

I need to skip the elements that have the "skipthis" class.

On the actual site, the elements with the "skipthis" class are hidden but still in the dom. This means the loop above is still counting them.

Right now, the output is something like this:

`1 list
2 list
4 list
5 list
6 list
etc.
etc.`

I need it to be 

`1 list 
2 list 
3 list 
4 list`

Comment: I would grab the li elements, and then use the hasClass to check if they are skipThis and splice them out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .hasClass() vs .is()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901553/jquery-hasclass-vs-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select all the elements that aren't skipthis and loop through to add:

```
$('#wpsl-stores li:not(.skipthis)').each(function(i,li) {
   $('body').append('<style>#wpsl-stores ul li:nth-child('+(i+1)+') strong:before {content:"'+(i+1)+'";}</style>');
});
```

EDIT:
If you want to remove the skipthis ones and add a counter to the others:

```
var listCount = 0;
$('#wpsl-stores li').each(function(i,li) {
   if ($(this).hasClass('skipthis')) {
      $(this).remove();
   } else {
      listCount++;   
      $('body').append('<style>#wpsl-stores ul li:nth-child('+listCount+') strong:before {content:"'+listCount+'";}</style>');
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you look at my updated question? Your solution is giving me the same output.

Comment: No, I am still getting the same problem. If the second `li` has the skipthis class than it's hidden but still in the dom. This means the third `li` is is getting "3" appended instead of "2".

Comment: Use remove then to take it out of the dom.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (i = 1; i < locCount+1; i++) {
  var $listElt = $('#wpsl-stores ul li:nth-child('+i+') strong:before');
  if (!$listElt.hasClass('skipThis') {
    $listElt.hide();

    $('body').append('<style>#wpsl-stores ul li:nth-child('+i+') strong:before {content:"'+i+'";}</style>');    
  }
}
```

[reference](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.not`

`$('#wpsl-stores li').not( ".skipthis" )`

source: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` for iteration and `.hasClass()` to skip some li elements:

```
$("#wpsl-stores li").each(function (index, element) {
   if (!$(element).hasClass('skipthis')) {
      // do something
   }
});
```